# Distribution over a matrix of probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, dirichlet-distribution

I am interested in a problem where I need to infer the distribution of a matrix of probabilities, $\matrix{\Theta}$, where the rows and columns must sum to 1 and every entry lie in the range 0 and 1.

Essentially I want to analyze the performance of a set of classifiers where $\theta_{ij}$ is the probability that a pattern belonging to class $i$ will be classified as belonging to class $j$ (for simplicity, I am assuming that $\matrix{\Theta}$ is the same for all classifiers).  The problem is that I don't know the true class of any of the observations, so I want to infer $\matrix{\Theta}$ from the labels assigned by each classifier (most of the observations will have been classified by two or more of the classifiers) in a Bayesian manner.  Hence I need to be able to define a distribution over $\matrix{\Theta}$.

I was thinking about some sort of product of Dirichlet distributions, representing each row and each column.  I'd be grateful for any better suggestions.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see why for each $j$ we must have that $\sum_i \theta_{ij} = 1$?

Comment: I'm not sure I can see why anymore either - been a long day, I'l have to think about it tomorrow.  It would make it much easier as then each row can be treated independently.  Good question!